# How do you add CSS with Javascript margin auto?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you add CSS rules using JavaScript?

For example

```
.center{margin:auto;width:900px}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector("#superman");
myElement.style.backgroundColor = "#D93600";
```